# Azure Spring Cloud - Add TLS/SSL binding fails during certificate import from Azure KeyVault

Tags: spring, azure, ssl-certificate, spring-cloud, azure-keyvault

I want to add an TLS/SSL binding for a custom domain of a deployed app in Azure Spring Cloud. During the import of the certificate from the Azure Key Vault I get an error:

Failed to import key vault cert. Reason: {"message":"An invalid value was provided for 'accessPolicies'.","errorStatusCode":400}

What I am doing wrong? It's not a very special topic. Nevertheless I didn't find anything about it :-(

It would be great if you can help!!!
best,
Stefano

Comment: Are you using azure CLI or power shell?

Comment: I am using powershell

Comment: How are you uploading the certificate into the key vault? What command do you use?